# How to convert binary message (Blob) obtained from WebSocket to forge's ByteBuffer?

Tags: javascript, encryption, forge

I am receiving binary message (Blob) from WebSocket which is, on the server side, encrypted using AES-CBC (openSSL). However, the decipher on the client side (JavaScript) returns true with empty output. In the listing below, encryptedMsg1 is msg.data obtained from webSocket (binary) which JavaScript debugger shows as Blob. It seems that my conversion from blob to forge's ByteStringBufer is not ok. I tried all I could but didn't manage. An attempt using ArrayBuffer from Blob is shown below (un and pwd is used also on the server side).

```
     function decode2(un, pwd, encryptedMsg1)
     {
        var md1 = forge.md.sha1.create();
        md1.update(un);
        var ivIn = md1.digest().getBytes(16);
        
        var ivType = typeof ivIn;
        
        var iv = ivIn;          
        
        var len = iv.length;
        
        var md256 = forge.md.sha256.create();
        md256.update(pwd);
        var key = md256.digest().getBytes();
        
        var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);
        decipher.start({iv: iv});
        var buffMsg=forge.util.createBuffer(encryptedMsg1, 'binary');
        decipher.update(buffMsg);
        var result = decipher.finish(); // check 'result' for true/false
        var txtOut = decipher.output.toHex();
        // outputs decrypted hex
        if (result)
            return decipher.output;
        
        return forge.util.createBuffer('ERR');
     }
```

Problem is in conversion from Blob to forge's ByteBuffer. Please, see figures for more details.

[Blob obtained after receiving binary message from WebSocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuEm1.jpg)

[Obtained Forge's ByteBuffer after using forge.util.createBuffer function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gEj9.jpg)

Link to forge: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge

Comment: There are many way to not get any results such as wrong encryption options as well as wrong encoding. Please provide the encryption and encoding code as well as example ciphertexts.

Comment: Problem is in conversion from Blob to forge's ByteBuffer. Blob was formed by WebSocket after receiving binary message. In this line: var var buffMsg=forge.util.createBuffer(encryptedMsg1, 'binary'); encryptedMsg1 is 96 bytes long, buffMsg is empty. How can I populate buffMsg from Blob?

Comment: Have you tried setting `ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'`? This will let ws stream output `ArrayBuffer` instead of `Blob` for binary data. `ws` is the WebSocket instance in browser.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks.